# Swift: how do you understand this function signature: func curry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C

Tags: swift

I see this function in the book *Functional Programming in Swift*, but I don't understand this function signature, what does the return type of this function mean?

```
func curry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C 
{ 
    return { x in { y in f(x, y) } }
}
```

**Edit:**

Is this function used like this?

```
fun add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

let curriedAdd = curry(add)

//to add 1 and 2
let resultOf1Plus2 = curriedAdd(1)(2)
```

Comment: oh the joy of seeing Mac programmers ask questions about function types.... thank you apple !

Comment: I find in Swift that removing whitespace and adding parentheses to compound types makes code like this much, much, _much_ easier to read.  So I would've written your function's first line as **`func curry<A,B,C>(f: (A,B)->C) -> (A)->(B->C)`**

Comment: Also, typealiases can make function-type-args much easier to read, so if this were my own code I would've probably settled on something like **`typealias CurryInFunc<A,B,C> = (A,B)->C; typealias CurryOutFunc<A,B,C> = (A)->((B)->C); func curry<A,B,C>(f: @escaping CurryInFunc<A,B,C>) -> CurryOutFunc<A,B,C> { … }`** _(testing & working in Swift 3)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function that takes one parameter of type `(A, B) -> C` (that is function taking two arguments and returning one) and returns `A -> B -> C` (that is, `A -> (B -> C)` i.e. function that takes one argument and returns function `B -> C`).

Currying "breaks" two argument function into two steps. Currying two argument function yields single argument function that returns another single argument function. That last function is equivalent to the original function with first parameter bound.

For example (in pseudocode, as I don't know Swift):

Having:

```
f: (X,Y) -> Z
cf = curry(f)
```

Then `f(x,y)` should be equivalent to `cf(x)(y)` for any `x,y`.

In your example, `resultOf1Plus2` should yield 3. However, you can "split" the process in the middle, and call

```
let increment = curriedAdd(1)
increment(2) // 3
increment(5) // 6
let addFive = curriedAdd(5)
addFive(5) // 10
```

which is not possible with plain `add` function.

See [Wikipedia article on currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

Comment: just my curiosity, A->B->C is considered A->(B->C) here, why isn't it considered as (A->B)->C, are there Swift grammar rules here?

Comment: Thank you, I understand currying, my problem is the type signature of this function here, this function should be understood in such way as in your answer, my problem is at grammar level.

Comment: See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1117): "**The function types of a curried function are grouped from right to left**. For instance, the function type `Int -> Int -> Int` is understood as `Int -> (Int -> Int)`—that is, a function that takes an `Int` and returns another function that takes and return an `Int`."

Comment: I think it's a feature borrowed from purely functional languages such as Haskell, because it's a standard feature there.

Answer (score 1):

`curry` takes a function that takes a pair of arguments of tyes A and B and returns a C.
It wraps this function in such a way that the result of `curry` is a function that takes a single argument of type A and returns another function. This other function takes a single argument of type B, and returns a C.

The effect is that where previously you had to supply both the A and B arguments to the original function at the same time, with the curried version you can supply the A argument first, and store the result with the captured A value, then supply the B argument at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

It is 'equivalent' to have a function of two arguments and to have a function of one argument tat returns a function of one argument.

The ability to go from one to the other *and back* defines what is called an isomorphism.

in the end

`curry . uncurry` leaves a function of one argument giving a function of one argument untouched
`uncurry . curry` leaves a function of two arguments untouched